# yaml modeling dynamic object properties

Tags: rest, dynamic, properties, yaml

I have a rest service that returns a list of objects.The client can filter the properties it wants in the response objects by providing an array of string(properties names) in request.
How can this be modeled in yaml?
There is a get request that returns all possible properties.

```
Request:
    type: array
    items: 
Field:
    type: string
```

The Response has to be an object with properties the values in provided Request object

Answer (score 0):

As you described, the request is just an array of strings, the response like an object.

So to model this in yaml, Request can be:

```
- Field1
- Field2
- Field3
```

Response can be:

```
Field1: "xxx yyy"
Field2: 33
Field3: 0.332
```